# Powershell-GUI filter for a list

Tags: powershell

I try to build search for a list form with Powershell-GUI.

```
$searchButton = GenerateButton -text 'search' -x 10 -y 280 -action {
    $data = $listForm.Items  -like "*$searchInput.Text*"
    $listForm.DataSource = $data
}
```

Filter `-like` does not work with objects.

Comment: If you want to compare something against the value of the `Text` property of `$searchInput` you have to use a subexpression inside the string (`"*$($searchInput.Text)*"`). However, I think that alone might not fix the issue, so please provide more context to both the code and what you're trying to achieve with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare something against the value of the `Text` property of `$searchInput` you have to use a subexpression inside the string:

```
$data = $listForm.Items  -like "*$($searchInput.Text)*"
```